# Unexpected behavior of LoggingErrorHandler in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

So, I have a camel context that has a `DeadLetterChannel` with no redeliveries at the context level. Within the context I have a route:

```
from("direct:input")
     .routeId("enrichHeader")
     .setHeader("myHeader").constant("someValue)
     .to("direct:output");
```

I have a unit test in which I `interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:output")` and cause an exception to be thrown.

Then in the unit test I do `producerTemplate.sendBody(theBody)`.

Now, as configured above on exception the message gets sent to the dead letter channel. All's well. However, if I configure a `loggingErrorHandler` I get odd behavior. So if I update the above route as follows:

```
from("direct:input")
     .routeId("enrichHeader")

     .errorHandler(
        loggingErrorHandler("com.myco.myproject")
             .level(LoggingLevel.WARN))

     .setHeader("myHeader").constant("someValue)
     .to("direct:output");
```

When I run the test now I get two unexpected behaviors. First, the exception is still logged at level `ERROR` instead of the configured `WARN`. Second, the exception is propagated back to the `producerTemplate.sendBody(theBody)` invokation.

On the one hand, the logging at `ERROR` is obviously odd. The other part that seems odd is that the handler is propagating the exception. I would have thought it would have marked it as handled and be done with it.

Is this expected behavior? Seems like documentation for the `LoggingErrorHandler` is lacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LoggingErrorHandler` do nothing more than logging the exception.
if you want to skip the exception you have to define a policy as followed

```
onException(com.myco.myproject.MyException.class).continued(true);
```

or you have to use a `doTry()..doCatch()` just like `try{...} catch{...}` block in java.

for example:

```
    from("direct:input").routeId("enrichHeader")
    .doTry()
        .setHeader("myHeader").constant("someValue)
        .to("direct:output")
    .doCatch(MyException.class)
        .process(new MYExceptionLoggerAndHandler())
   .end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wish this was documented.